# Pass comma separated string as second argument to batch file C#

Tags: c#, batch-file

I have a batch file that takes two arguments 
Arg1: string 
Arg2: a string of comma separated strings  (like 123S,123A,123B,..)

Inside the batch file I am assigning the above arguments as input to a exe. When I run the batch file I see that Arg2 is been taken as just 123S instead of 123S,123A,123B.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the batch file code

`set p1=%1

set p2=%2

MyApp.exe -Class "%p1%" -Query "(Model=%p2%)"`

This is how I am calling the batch file from C#

```
var processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(txtBatchFileLocation.Text); 
processInfo.Arguments = string.Format(cmbClass.SelectedItem.ToString() + " " + item.Value);
using (Process process = Process.Start(processInfo))
{
     process.WaitForExit();
     process.Close();
}
```

Comment: How are the parameters passed to the batch file?

Comment: Use `"string"` as Arg1, and `"123S,123A,123B,…"` as Arg2. It's always safer to doublequote your arguments. Then in your batch-file don't set variables unnecessarily, just use `MyApp -Class %1 -Query "(Model=%~2)"`, _(`%~2` will expand the argument removing its outer doublequotes)_.

Comment: "(Model=%~2)" Didn't work. How do I doublequote the argument in C#?

Comment: \"(Model=%~2)\" escape with backslash?

Comment: @subbu, `"(Model=%~2)"` in a batch-file which receives its second argument as `"123S,123A,123B,…"` will look like this `"(Model=123S,123A,123B,…)"`. The advice I gave does work, if your `MyApp.exe` does not accept `-Class "string" -Query "(Model=123S,123A,123B,…)"`, then that is not my fault, and most certainly does not invalidate the advice I provided.

Comment: This worked for me. Thanks to @Compo and @Oguz for correcting me. `string strArgClass = "\"" + cmbClass.SelectedItem.ToString() + "\"";
                string strArgQuery = "\"" + item.Value + "\"";
                var processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(txtBatchFileLocation.Text);
                processInfo.Arguments = string.Format(strArgClass + " " + strArgQuery);`